# Editing a list of structured items in React: where to keep the state for not-currently-valid values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, typing

I'm working on a React component that displays a list of items, and allows the user to add, remove, and edit the items. I want the component to have an API somewhat like this:

```
<ListEditor values={/* an array of items */} setValues={/* function to replace that array with its argument */}>
```

Inside the component there is probably a `<ListItemEditor>` for each item, and an `<AddButton>` to append a new item.

For the sake of the argument, let's say the values consist of a number of vowels, which must not be zero, and a word with that number of vowels, which must not be empty. And maybe a random ID for React keeping them straight. Each list item would then have a number input for number of vowels, and a text box for the word.

```
let values = [{"id": 123, "vowels": 2, "word": "seat"}, {"id": 456, "vowels": 1, "word": "cat"}]
```

**If I want only valid items to propagate outside of the `ListEditor`, what is the idiomatic way or structure in React for the `ListEditor` or its subcomponents to store state related to *invalid* items which the user is in the process of editing?**

For example, the `ListEditor` is going to have an "Add" button, and when the user clicks it, a new item needs to pop up to be filled in. That new item needs to display the same controls as the items actually in the list, but it can't actually *be* in the list in `values`, or be passed to `setValues`, until the user has entered a number of vowels and a word that agrees with it.

Similarly, if the user goes to an entry and increments the number of vowels on it by 1, the word that's stored there can't be used anymore; the user needs to enter a new word with the right number of vowels before `setValues` can be called.

If the user adds new items at positions 3, 5, and 7 in the list, enters valid values into the first and third one, and then something else on the page removes item 9, I would *like* the in-progress items to still be there, but it's OK if that's not feasible without something heavy-weight like Redux, and the user needs to have exclusive control of the list or risk losing work.

Right now I think I need something like a shadow version of the incoming props as state in each component, and the component will actually live-update and render *that*, and will call its provided callback only when the shadow state passes internal validation and looks like an allowed argument for the callback. Is that the way people usually do this? Is the top-level API I want just a bad one and I should let invalid data out of the component after all?